# Find Groups of data that could have a change in a second related column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table of information that I need to find groups of column one, that could possible have a change in column two.

Here is some sample data.

123464 A
123464 B
123456 A
123457 A
123458 A
123459 B
123459 B
123459 C
123460 A
123461 T
123462 A
123463 B
123465 V
123466 B

What I am expecting the query to do, is find
123459
123464

I have tried to do some grouping with a having, but have had no success in getting anything useful.  I know there are some SQL wizards out there.  I think I am trying too hard and there is probably a simple solution.

I am working in DB2, but if someone comes up with the solution I would happily port it over to DB2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or something like this might work and doesn't involve a join:

```
SELECT column1
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY column1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT columns2) > 1
```

Comment: I like the result (verified working on full data set).  How does this work?  The grouping works to consolidate the duplicates in col1, but how does the count(distinct col2) work?

Comment: I believe count distinct simply counts all distinct values in an entire column and in this case your just looking for when this is greater than 1 against your first colummn